# I'm older than the Polish study visa age limit; what can I do?

Tags: student-visa, poland

I recently received a confirmation letter from university of Lodz in Poland and while I was preparing for my VISA application I found out that there is an age limit in the embassy website for my country Algeria.

My question is : I'm 31 years old and limit age is 25 to be eligible for studies, what should I do in this case ?

http://www.algier.msz.gov.pl/fr/service_consulaire/visas/etudes/

Prerequisites
To be eligible to study in Poland, you must have the following prerequisites:
1. PREPARATORY COURSES FOR APPLICANTS IN HIGHER POLISH-COMPULSORY STUDIES:

Duration: One year (900 hours)

in a school designated by the Ministry of Education and Higher Education (Disposition of the Minister of Education and Higher Education, OJ of 2006, No. 190, art 1406 on the registration and prosecution of higher education and training, participation in scientific research and development work by foreigners).

WARNING: The Polish Embassy is not responsible for students' financial commitments to schools or the credibility of private schools in Poland.

**2. AGE LIMIT OF ADMISSION: 25 years, regardless of the diplomas obtained after the high school diploma and the cycle of studies requested.**

Comment: I just went to their Polish version website and there is no evidence of this limit of age ?   http://www.algier.msz.gov.pl/pl/informacje_konsularne/wizy/wizy_polska/

Answer (score 8):

I just contacted the embassy consular service, they told me it is nothing you could come for your VISA appointment next week.

There is no limit age

Answer (score -1):

Yes there is no problem about your age as long as you already have bachelor or master degree and you would like to continue your own studies in Poland ;) let us know if your visa interview went well and what type of questions you've been asked by VO?  Share with us ashour 10

Good luck

Comment: Welcome to Expats.SE. We tend to like our answers to be evidence based. Do you have a link to documentation that says it is not a problem?

Comment: Everything went well, questions were, as usual, what do you know about Poland, why did choose Poland, what do you think about your current situation in Algeria and what are your plans after you finish

Comment: Okey cool , did you get the visa or not yet? Did you give them all documents that required for visa ? Like health insurance , open flight ticket , bank account if you can detail your documents thx ?