# I'm 29 years old from Zambia, can I apply for student visa?

Tags: student-visa, poland

Is there age limit to get a Polish student visa?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [I'm older than the Polish study visa age limit; what can I do?](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/12108/im-older-than-the-polish-study-visa-age-limit-what-can-i-do)